# How should I show that the nontrivial solutions of the given differential equation have infinitely many zeros in $(0, \infty)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $k$ be a constant positive integer. Show that the nontrivial solutions of the equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y(1+x^{k})=0$ have infinitely many zeros in $(0, \infty)$. Show also that the separation between adjacent zeros tends to zero as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Here's my work:

By using the substitution $y=e^{rx}, y'=re^{rx}, y''=r^2e^{rx}$, we get $r^2e^{rx}+e^{rx}(1+x^{k})=0$.

Factoring out $e^{rx}$ gives us $e^{rx}(r^2+1+x^{k})=0$.

Now we have $r^2+1+x^{k}=0\implies r=\pm\sqrt{-1-x^{k}}$.

Thus, the general solution is $y(x)=c_{1}e^{\sqrt{-1-x^{k}}x}+c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{-1-x^{k}}x}$.

From here, what should I do in order to show that the nontrivial solutions of this differential equation have infinitely many zeros in $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: $$c_1 \mathrm e^{\sqrt{-(1+x^k)}~x}+c_2\mathrm e^{\sqrt{-(1+x^k)}~x} = a\cos(\sqrt{1+x^k}~x)+b\sin((\sqrt{1+x^k}~x))=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\sqrt{1+x^k}~x + \varphi)$$

Comment: There is no solution of the form $y = e^{rx}$ with **fixed** $r$. So your approach does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) $u(x)=\sin(x)$ is a non-trivial solution to $y''+y=0$, with zeros at $x_n=n\pi\,(n\in\mathbb{Z})$. Hence, according to the [Sturm-Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem), since $1+x^k>1$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$, if $v$ a non-trivial solution to $y''+(1+x^k)y=0$, it has a zero in each interval $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]\,(n\in\mathbb{N})$. Therefore, $v$ has infinitely many zeros in $(0,\infty)$.

b) Similarly, $u(x)=\sin(M^{k/2}x)$ is a non-trivial solution to $y''+M^ky=0$, with zeros at $x_n=nM^{-k/2}\pi \,(M>0, n\in\mathbb{Z})$. According to the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, since $1+x^k>M^k$ if $x\in(M,\infty)$, a non-trivial solution $v$ to $y''+(1+x^k)y=0$ has a zero in each interval $[nM^{-k/2}\pi ,(n+1)M^{-k/2}\pi]$ such that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $nM^{-k/2}\pi>M$. Hence, if $x', x''$ are two adjacent zeros of $v$ in $(M,\infty)$, then $|x'-x''|<2M^{-k/2}\pi$. This inequality implies that $|x'-x''|\to 0$ as $M\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much!